# spring retryable database connection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot application that I'm deploying to an Azure App Service. This application connects to a MySQL server. I would like that the application would retry the database connection. I looked around for a solution and I found [this blog post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/spring-boot-retry-database-connection-startup-abdelghani-roussi?articleId=6723332249346981888).

**My question**: is there any spring setting that would do this? I honestly expected that the database connection would retry by default since it's kinda annoying to break the app if for a split second the connection drops.